# Java Tomcat, underlying Netty threads not stopped

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, log4j2, graylog2

I'm trying to use a log4j appender to send logs to GrayLog2 (`log4j2-gelf`). So I add my dependency to my `pom.xml` configure the `log4j2.xml` to configure my appender. Build the whole thing with maven and deploy it to a local tomcat, and everything works fine.
The problem happen when I try to shutdown the tomcat.
Tomcat does not stop if I don't `kill -9 PID` the tomcat and the `catalina.out` ends up with this : [Complete stack trace](http://pastebin.com/G5xJN7Af)

What got my attention is the

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise$1

First I thought that I may have another dependency importing netty that would cause this exception. But I've looking for some time and was not able to find any other netty import. Then I saw the :

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web
>   application instance has been stopped already. Could not load
>   [io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$1]. The following stack trace is thrown for
>   debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which
>   caused the illegal access.

And this is where my question is coming.
My understanding is that the gelf-appender is using Netty as a way to communicate asynchronously with the GrayLog server. But it's a server itself. So would it be possible that the Tomcat is stopping the parent servlet before killing the underlying Netty ? Which would lead to this problem ?
I've trying to find some documentation on the way that Tomcat shutsdown, but so far I did not find anything, more than that I could perfectly be wrong concerning this diagnostic...

Comment: I've doing some digging and it seems that I cannot reproduce the problem with Jetty, so this looks like a tomcat issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have a ClassLoader problem

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load
>   [io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$1]. The following stack trace is thrown for
>   debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which
>   caused the illegal access.
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1342)

`WebappClassLoader` stops serving incoming request to load, when it receives shutdown signal. You need Netty jar be accessible beyond `WebappClassLoader`. Put it to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` (see [Tomcat classloader howto, section Common](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)). To find the right jar, run `mvn dependency:tree` for your webapp (if you use maven)

Comment: It does fix the problem. Thanks a lot mate !